# How to improve performance when drawing with nested loops?

Tags: python, performance, nested-loops

I've developed a procedure that procedurally generate a dungeon with mazes:

```
entities = {}
dungeonSize = 8
currentDungeon = (randint(0,dungeonSize-1),randint(0,dungeonSize-1))
lOR = 16 # Level of Randomness.

def gD(): # Generate Dungeon

    for i in range(dungeonSize):
        for j in range(dungeonSize):
            entities[(j,i)] = {}

    for dungeon in entities:
        r = randint(0,lOR)
        for k in range(16):
            for l in range(16):
                if randint(0,lOR*2) == 0:
                    for m in range(r):
                        entities[dungeon][((((l+m)*brickWidth),(k*brickHeight)))] = {"source":"brick.jpg",
                                            "info":["dungeon wall",u"parede da masmorra"]}     
                elif randint(0,lOR*2) == 1:
                    for m in range(r):
                        entities[dungeon][(((l*brickWidth),(k+m)*brickHeight))] = {"source":"brick.jpg",
                                            "info":["dungeon wall",u"parede da masmorra"]}
```

It happens that I need to draw the current screen/maze at each frame (Each tile of the ground and each of the walls). It also happens to be REALLY complicated in this case to keep track of the tiles that have changed or anything like that to save some memory.

Here's the drawing-procedure that goes at the main loop:

```
def dCD(): # Draw Current Dungeon

    for wall in entities[currentDungeon]:
        gIS("GFX",entities[currentDungeon][wall]["source"],wall[0],wall[1])
```

The ground is also drawn at each frame (I can't use a single image because I'll create random kinds of tiles).

```
def fWG(): # Fill with Ground

    for i in range(16):
        for j in range(16):
            gIS("GFX",ground,j*brickWidth,i*brickHeight)
```

Is there a way to "free a Surface" in Pygame, or anyway to blit ALL these surfaces and have some 20+ FPS? (I'm currently having 8 FPS. Really laggy!). If there is not, what you suggest? Writing the game in C, thinking on a more clever algorithm to magically replace and erase and reutilize tiles at each frame?

Comment: Could you post your `gIS` function and all other functions that draw something or create surfaces (text included)?

Comment: Why do you need so many different dungeons?

Comment: Advice: I suggest to name your `gD()` function little more explanatory, for example `generate_dungeon()`. You should do it with all your functions. `print()` is called `print()` for a reason, `p()` wouldn't give you as much information and the code would be harder to read.